# Show $(y/2)/\sqrt{1-x^y}$ is bounded by one for $x\in(0,3/4)$ and $y\in(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I would like to show that for all $x\in(0,3/4)$ and $y\in(0,1)$ that $f(x,y) = \frac{y}{2\sqrt{1-x^y}}$ is bounded above by one.

My thought is that for any $x$ I can try to show it an increasing function of $y$ on $(0,1)$. Then it would be bounded by $f(x,1) \leq 1$. To do this I computed the derivative wrt $y$ $\frac{df}{dy} (x,y) = \frac{2(1-x^y)+x^y\log(x^y)}{4 (1-x^y)^{3/2}}$, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I feel like there must be some bound for logs which I can apply here to show the derivative is non-negative.

Comment: You can pretty easily show monotonicity on x for fixed y (without calculus), so you can auto-set x=3/4. In particular, $x^y$ is monotonic so $1-x^y$ is, so $\sqrt{1-x^y} is ...

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

I think I might have figured it out:

Consider the function
\begin{align*}
    g(x,y) = \frac{y}{2\sqrt{1-x^y}}.
\end{align*}
This function is clearly increasing (thanks [@Eric](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/909833/eric)) in $x$ for all $y\in(0,1)$, so it suffices to set $x=3/4$.
Thus, define
\begin{align*}
    f(y) = \log \left( \frac{y}{2\sqrt{1-(3/4)^y}} \right)
\end{align*}
which has derivative
\begin{align*}
    f'(y) = \frac{1}{y} - \frac{\log(4/3)}{2((4/3)^y-1)}.
\end{align*}
We aim to show $f'(y)$ is non-negative.
Note that $(4/3)^y-1 > \log(4/3)y$ for all $y$ so
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\log(4/3)}{2((4/3)^y-1)}
    \leq \frac{\log(4/3)}{2 \log(4/3)y}
    = \frac{1}{2y}.
\end{align*}
Therefore $f'(y) \geq 1/(2y) \geq 0$ so $f(y)$ is monotonic. This implies that $g(3/4,y)$ is also monotonic, so it is bounded by $g(3/4,1) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

The function is monotonic increase in both $x$ and $y$ so you need test the corner case $(3/4,1)$, where the value is $1$.

[image]

We know the function is monotonic in each variable:

- Hold $y$ constant... as $x$ gets bigger, the denominator gets smaller, so the function gets bigger.
- Hold $x$ constant... as $y$ gets bigger, the numerator gets bigger linearly, and the denominator gets larger but less than linearly, and hence the overall function gets bigger.

Comment: Yes, I have made this same plot, but I am asking how to prove the function is monotonic. Is it clear from the form of the function or are you just getting this from the plot?

Comment: @tch +1 : I just upvoted your query, both for good work shown, and for the **outstanding** comment/question that you just asked.  Although it is postponing the inevitable attack on $\frac{df}{dy} f(x,y)$ now is a reasonable moment for you to edit your query to compute $\frac{df}{dx} f(x,y)$, which you will have to do anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure its true the denominator gets smaller as $y$ increases. As $y$ increases from $0$ to $1$ $x^y$ goes from $1$ to $x$ so  $\sqrt{1-x^y}$ increases.

Comment: How does one quantify the growth of "less than linearly" over non-asymptotics?